# Android layout: scrolling list with header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is not a design question, I have the item designed. I am confused on how to pull it off.

I am tasked with designing a view for Android that has a view of a user's post and the comments under it. The post contains some extra information and widely different design from the comments, but all of them need to scroll in tandem, like a web page would (*Oh, how I am spoiled by my years of web dev...*).

My current solution is to nest a `LinearLayout` (at the top of the view to contain the user's post) and a `RecyclerView` (below the post to display the comments) inside a vertical `ScrollView`. The information is actually displayed, but the `RecyclerView`, of course, scrolls independently of the `LinearLayout` above it and ruins the functionality of the view.

**I wish, if possible, to keep the `RecyclerView` in use**

The best case scenario would be to have the LinearLayout with the post scroll a certain amount, and then the `RecyclerView` take over. **However**, I don't want to poison my codebase with 200+ ugly lines of code to achieve this, so if this is a laborious task to complete, I would rather look for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is: do you really need a `RecyclerView`, or even better, do you really need *recycling*?

If the answer is **yes**, the way to go is two different item types in the `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` (for more details, see [here](https://medium.com/@paulnunezm/working-with-recyclerview-and-multiple-view-types-bb1e7dfc6993) or [here](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e)). This concept was already present in the `ListView`: the main difference is that `RecyclerView` enforce the use of the View Holder pattern. It is not so complex, and, more importantly, is the way the `RecyclerView` is supposed to solve that problem. Depending on your UI design, you may also want to have different view types for different types of comments (plain text, images, ...). Remember that, when the `RecyclerView` is included in a `ScrollView`, the recycling won't work, because all the items in it will be drawn at once to compute the height of the content of the parent `ScrollView`.

If the answer is **no**, then you could just create your views at runtime and add them to a parent `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`. It is really nothing more than a for loop.

A more fancy approach would be to use an `ItemDecoration` for the user's post, but I don't see any specific advantage in this case.

Comment: Posts may have 100+ comments, each may or may not have images. Recycling would be very important to performance in this instance. I think different types of items in the RecyclerView is a good way to go, can you please link some relevant videos/ articles?